# need to retrieve the details for doctor name in the table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, repository-pattern

I am calling the below method in my code , but not able to form the expression tree , please suggest .

```
m1.FindSingleBy<Doctor_Details>( m1 => m1.Doctor_Name == "a");


public virtual T FindSingleBy<T>(Expression<Func<T , bool>> predicate) where T : class
    {
        if (predicate != null)
        {

            Dolphin_PatientEntities1 contxt = new Dolphin_PatientEntities1();
            using (contxt)
            {
                return contxt.Set<T>().Where(predicate).SingleOrDefault();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Predicate value must be passed to FindSingleBy<T>.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I downvote this question, because it contains no code, no questions and asks to write code for the author.

Answer (score 3):

In Entity Framework, the `DbSet<T>` class is your repository and `DbContext` is your `UnitofWork`. In the `Dbset<T>`, you have methods like `Add()`, `Find()`, `Remove()`, `Where()` etc.

> It maintains lists of business objects in-memory which have been
>   changed (inserted, updated, or deleted) during a transaction. Once the
>   transaction is completed, all these updates are sent as one big unit
>   of work to be persisted physically in a database in one go.

for more information check[Unit of Work](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/581487/Unit-of-Work-Design-Pattern)

Comment: thanks , but can you explain the concept of unit of work in detail.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest to follow below mentioned article to learn `repository and unit of work patterns`.If you have any question after following it,feel free to ask it again.

> The repository and unit of work patterns are intended to create an
>   abstraction layer between the data access layer and the business logic
>   layer of an application. Implementing these patterns can help insulate
>   your application from changes in the data store and can facilitate
>   automated unit testing or test-driven development (TDD).

[image]

**This is the Article :** [**Implementing the Repository and Unit of Work Patterns**](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 0):

I am new to repository pattern but where do you usually store the result so you are not hitting the database everytime? Entity Framework takes care of this?